# 2D Movement Simulator (Similar to American Football Playbook)

Tags: java, flash, 2d, simulation

I am new to programming and wanted to create a program that allows users to create and model movements on a 2D plain. It will be something that is relatively simple such as X's and O's moving that based on the user's direction. I want the user to be able to create and direct the movement of each individual unit (the X's and O's). I am trying to decide which language would allow me to create this that does not have a steep learning curve, since I would be learning it from scratch for this project. Not sure if it makes a difference, but I want to be able to share this program on my website. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you also want to use your program on website, Unity could be a good choice. It also quite simple and have a lot of examples. When you will build your program you can build it for Windows,MAC,Mobile or Web.

You can code in Unity script (similar to JS) and C#.
https://unity3d.com/

Comment: So I would be able create a game where the user can place the X's and O's where they want on a plain in models and have them move from accordingly? Example:

Formation 1:

X  O  X  O  X


Formation 2:

X      X      X

    O      O

Formation 3:

    O      O

X      X      X

So I would want to have to different points (X's and O's) moving in a continuous flow from 

Formation 1 --> Formation 2 --> Formation 3

Would I be able to do that using unity?